# How to obtain the option selected from the drop down menu and insert it into a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've been trying to do a dynamic drop down menu using php/mysql with ajax. But I'm new to php and ajax so i don't know how to insert the selected option into a mysql table. I created a form where the action leads to a insertsql.php file but its not working.I'm using wamp server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

index1.php

```
<?php
//index.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "projects");
$pname = '';
$query = "SELECT pname FROM project_details GROUP BY pname ORDER BY pname ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $pname .= '<option value="'.$row["pname"].'">'.$row["pname"].'</option>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>zz
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />

  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">Dynamic Dependent Select Box using JQuery Ajax with PHP</h2><br /><br />
  <form  method = "POST" action = "insertsql.php" >
 <select name="pname" id="pname" class="form-control action">
    <option value="">Select Project</option>
    <?php echo $pname; ?>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="user" id="user" class="form-control action">
    <option value="">Select User Name</option>
   </select>
   <br />
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
<p id="dem"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>


</form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.action').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() != '')
  {
   var action = $(this).attr("id");
   var query = $(this).val();
   var result = '';
   if(action == "pname")
   {
    result = 'user';
   }

   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{action:action, query:query},
    success:function(data){
     $('#'+result).html(data);

    }
   })
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

fetch.php

```
    <?php
//fetch.php
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "projects");
 $output = '';
 if($_POST["action"] == "pname")
 {


  $query = "SELECT fname,lname FROM users WHERE pname = '".$_POST["query"]."' GROUP BY fname";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  $output .= '<option value="">Select User</option>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '<option value="'.$row["fname"].' '.$row["lname"].'">'.$row["fname"]." ".$row["lname"].'</option>';
  }

 }

 echo $output;

}
?>
```

Comment: you do not have a form element with name="action"

Comment: @delboy1978uk `action` is passed via AJAX call.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What is it doing that it should not, or what is it not doing that it should. You just described what you wanted to do, but have not told us what errors, or result you are or are not getting from what you are attempting. Your question seems to hinge on 'inserting data', but all of this is getting data...

Comment: Right now the drop down menu is working properly. The thing i'm not able to insert the option which was selected into the mysql table i.e. $pname= $_POST['pname'] is not returning any value. I don't know much about ajax so i'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Well... I don't see ajax for the actual sending to be inserted part. Also you left out the php for what you are attempting for the actual insert operation. There are multiple ways you can go with this... but first question would be: do you want the user to stay on the same page during submit for insert? Or are you going to head them to a mostly new page result?

Comment: No the user will be redirected to a page which simply displays the values entered in the form by the user.

Comment: I did it....I did it. It was one simple syntax error in the insert statement...Thank you so much for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

insertsql.php

```
<?php
include('sqlconfig.php');

$pname= $_POST['pname'];
$username=$_POST['user'];
$date=$_POST['wdate'];
$hours=$_POST['hours'];
echo "$pname";

echo "<br>$username<br>";
$sql="INSERT INTO worklogging(pname,username,wdate,wkhours) VALUES ('$pname','$username','$date','$hours')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {echo 'not inserted';}
else
{echo 'Inserted';
}
?>
```

This is the part where the data from the dropdown menu is inserted into the mysql table. Thank you all for the help :)